# How to press 'Enter' without targeting a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I make tests with WebDriver and at a moment a popup appears, with no fixed attribute (auto-generated).

So, the simplest way (I think) is to press the key 'Enter' on the keyboard.
But I can't find the way to say 'Just click on the browser, not on an element of the browser'.

It's possible with WebDriver? How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An alternative is to use the java.awt.Robot to simulate a keyboard's interaction and not a WebElement's treatment.

`[WebDriver code]`

```
try {
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.delay(200);
}
```

`[WebDriver code]`

Answer (score 2):

```
  Robot robot = new Robot();
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); //press enter key
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); //release enter key
```

You should specify the release command also while the enter key has been pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Actions utility we can achieve the same:

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.RETURN).keyUp(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();
```

Comment: The logic looks good, but I can not execute it without crashing. And the popup does not disappear ..
thank you as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

Comment: thank you very much! it really helps me! For cons of both the application crashes after this command. So I framed by a 'try {} catch () {}' to prevent the crash.